# Why is the new JWT refresh token not getting verified in node.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, redis, jwt

I am building a blog application using node.js, expressjs and mongodb. I created a user login authentication system using jwt. I am still learning using the process.
The login works and the JWT access and refresh tokens get generated. The access token is to expire in 1 minute and a refresh token route will be used to generate another access token for the user.
That works. But I noticed that the new generated refresh token is not working. I mean, it doesn't pass the jwt verification call via jwt.verification() method. Only the refresh token generated during the point of login gets verified. I don't know if this is how it should work or I'm missing something.

What I want exactly is that when a user logs-in, the user generates access token and refresh token. The access token expires in 1 minute and the user will have to regenerate access token using the refresh token he got at the point of sign in. This refresh token will be used via the refresh route.
When the user uses the refresh route to generate new access token, he also generates a new refresh token as well. I would like that new refresh token to be able to work too while the previous refresh token stops working immediately.
That means, immediately a user uses the refresh route to generate new access and refresh tokens, the previous refresh token will no longer work while the new refresh token will be used next time the user wants to regenerate another access and refresh tokens via the refresh route. The refresh tokens are saved in redis database.

Here are my codes:

```
//login

const User = require("../models/User");

const login = async (req, res) =>{
 try {
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    let passValidate
    if(user) {
        passValidate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    }

    if(!user || !passValidate || user.role === "admin") {
        res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
    } else {
        const {password, ...others} = user._doc;

        //generate access token
        const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id, username:user.username, role: user.role}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_LIFETIME});

        //generate refresh token
         const refresh_Token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id, username:user.username, role: user.role}, process.env.Refresh_Secret);
         //check refreshtoken in redis database

         await client.get(user._id.toString(), (err, data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

        //set refresh token in redis database
            client.set(user._id.toString(), JSON.stringify(refresh_Token));
         }); 
        res.status(200).json({user: {username: user.username, userId: user._id}, token, refresh_Token})
    } 
} catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
}
```

Login route

```
const {register, login, admin} = require('../controller/auth');
router.post('/login', login);
```

Access token verification

```
const verify = (req, res, next) =>{
const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
if(authHeader){
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
} else{
    res.status(401).json("You're not authenticated")
}
}

module.exports = verify
```

Codes to verify refresh token and regenerate new access token and refresh token

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const redis_client = require('../reditConnect');


const refreshTokenverify = async (req, res, next) =>{
const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
if(authHeader){
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    if(!token) return res.status(401).json({status: false, message: "No token found"});

    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.Refresh_Secret);
        req.owner = decoded;
        console.log(decoded)

        //verify if token is in redis store
    await redis_client.get(decoded.userId.toString(), (err, data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        if(data === null) return res.status(401).json({message: "Token not found in database"});
        if(JSON.parse(data).refresh_Token != token) return res.status(401).json({message: "Invaid request"});
        console.log(req)
        
    })
    next()

    }catch(error){
        return res.status(401).json({message: "Your session is not valid"})
    }
} else{
    res.status(401).json("You're not authenticated")
}
}
const regenrateToken = async (req, res)=>{
 
 const token = jwt.sign({userId: req.owner.userId, username:req.owner.username, role: req.owner.role}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
 expiresIn: process.env.JWT_LIFETIME});

 const refresh_Token = jwt.sign({userId: req.owner._id, username:req.owner.username, role: req.owner.role}, process.env.Refresh_Secret);

 await redis_client.set(req.owner.userId.toString(), JSON.stringify(refresh_Token))
 res.status(401).json({data: {token, refresh_Token}})
 console.log(req)
 };



 module.exports = {refreshTokenverify,
  regenrateToken
  }
```

Refresh route to verify refresh token and generate new access and refresh tokens

```
const {refreshTokenverify, regenrateToken} = require('../middleware/refreshTokenVerify');

router.post('/refresh', refreshTokenverify, regenrateToken);
```

Error that I got from postman when I tried to use the new refresh token user got via the refresh route

```
{
"message": "Your session is not valid"
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems valid to me, but I notice one thing. Since you are throwing the error from the Redis call in the `refreshTokenVerify`

```
//verify if token is in redis store
await redis_client.get(decoded.userId.toString(), (err, data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        if(data === null) return res.status(401).json({message: "Token not found in database"});
        if(JSON.parse(data).refresh_Token != token) return res.status(401).json({message: "Invaid request"});
        console.log(req)
        
    })
```

I'm not sure how did you conclude the error is coming from `jwt.verify()` call?

You could try console logging the error message along with sending out an invalid token response

Comment: I checked properly using console.log and I discovered that the refresh token under the function regenrateToken() has undefined userId and username. Because I tried using the refresh token generated when the regenrateToken() function is called and it returned token for sure but has undefined user at all. That is strange and I think that is where the problem comes from.

Comment: You are using `req.owner.userId` when signing jwt inside `regenerateToken()` and `req.owner._id` for signing refresh_token. I think we have found your error :)

Comment: I just corrected that but that didnt solve the problem. Do you think that I need to find the user again under the regerateToken() function and attached to id and username inside the refreshtoken?

Comment: I'm just confused. When the refresh token is coming from the first point of sign in. That is the refresh token that the user gets when he signs in, I console.log(req.user) in the regenarateToken() and found the user details there. When the user now uses refresh route after the first token has expired and generate new access and refresh token, I then tried to use that newly regenerated refresh token that came from the refresh route, the console.log(req) has no user details. This got me confused becus before the refresh token was generated, the user signed in and the details were there.

Comment: Though the refresh token regenerated from the refresh route worked and got verified and generated new access token and refresh token when I removed the redis data codes. I think why the redis database codes failed was because there are no user details for the redis to get the id from.